# Debug Java / Tomcat application creating internal connections

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat7

I have a web application deployed in tomcat that has too many connections like the highlighted below. I would like to know which module/library is creating such connections.

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8009           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       268
  TCP    0.0.0.0:8080           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8005         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44251        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44252        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44257        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44258        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44260        127.0.0.1:3306         ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44261        127.0.0.1:44262        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44262        127.0.0.1:44261        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44263        127.0.0.1:44264        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44264        127.0.0.1:44263        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44265        127.0.0.1:44266        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44266        127.0.0.1:44265        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44267        127.0.0.1:44268        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44268        127.0.0.1:44267        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44269        127.0.0.1:44270        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44270        127.0.0.1:44269        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44271        127.0.0.1:44272        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44272        127.0.0.1:44271        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44273        127.0.0.1:44274        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44274        127.0.0.1:44273        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44275        127.0.0.1:44276        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44276        127.0.0.1:44275        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44277        127.0.0.1:44278        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44278        127.0.0.1:44277        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44279        127.0.0.1:44280        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44280        127.0.0.1:44279        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44281        127.0.0.1:44282        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44282        127.0.0.1:44281        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44283        127.0.0.1:44284        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44284        127.0.0.1:44283        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44285        127.0.0.1:44286        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44286        127.0.0.1:44285        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44287        127.0.0.1:44288        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44288        127.0.0.1:44287        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44289        127.0.0.1:44290        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44290        127.0.0.1:44289        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44291        127.0.0.1:44292        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44292        127.0.0.1:44291        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44293        127.0.0.1:44294        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    127.0.0.1:44294        127.0.0.1:44293        ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    192.168.1.128:8080     192.168.1.128:43916    ESTABLISHED     268
  TCP    192.168.1.128:8080     192.168.1.128:44295    ESTABLISHED     268
```

If you look at the connections there are connection pairs.
Eg:

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:44265        127.0.0.1:44266
 TCP    127.0.0.1:44266        127.0.0.1:44265
```

These connection pairs run into 1000s of connections in certain cases.
We do not create these connection pairs manually. We use a library that manages socket connections to an external device. The library in turn uses apache mina.
What are the possible ways to debug this weird connection pairs?

Answer (score 0):

Generate a heap dump and use a tool to analyze it.  This will tell you what class is creating all of the connection objects.

https://dzone.com/articles/java-heap-dump-analyzer-1